# Date / Timestamp to record when a record was added to the table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Does anyone know of a function as such that I can use to add an automatic date and timestamp in a column for when a user adds a record to the database table?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Not a duplicate since he's asking for a creation timestamp only.

Comment: Ok, so she can ignore the trigger part. The answer from @marc_s says just about as much as most of the 5 new answers below.

Comment: This question is subject of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309460/5108803

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can create a non-nullable DATETIME column on your table, and create a DEFAULT constraint on it to auto populate when a row is added.

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE Example
(
SomeField INTEGER,
DateCreated DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT(GETDATE())
)
```

Comment: I am in the process of adding an extra column name (DateCreated) to my table and have set the 'DataType' to 'Datetime'.  I have set the 'Allow Nulls' to 'No' and just need to enter the DEFAULT(GETDATE()).  I am completing this above exercise by right clicking on the table and 'Modifying' it.  I cant see an option / area to add the DEFAULT(GETDATE()) function to?  Any Ideas?

Comment: @Betty in the grid below, there is a cell called "Default value of binding" - you would enter `GETDATE()` there. However, I strongly recommend learning `CREATE TABLE` and `ALTER TABLE` and using a query window for these things - the visual designers are not the best way.

Comment: @AdaTheDev,  sorry but i have found this location now within the properties.  Many thanks for your help you have been most helpful.

Answer (score 8):

You can make a default constraint on this column that will put a default getdate() as a value.

Example:

```
alter table dbo.TABLE 
add constraint df_TABLE_DATE default getdate() for DATE_COLUMN
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `datetime` field and set it's default value to `GetDate()`.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [TimeStamp] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Test_TimeStamp] DEFAULT (GetDate()),
    [Foo] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass `GetDate()` function as an parameter to your insert query
e.g

```
Insert into table (col1,CreatedOn) values (value1,Getdate())
```

Comment: @Aaron.  Many thanks for your help as this has worked a treat.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [DateAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) on a trigger or a computed column if the timestamp you are adding is fixed or dependent of another column