# Insert an "insertion date" value into a SQL table automatically?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to define a datetime column and populate it automatically when a row is inserted, without having to use a trigger?

The value would be the point in time when the row was inserted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Date / Timestamp to record when a record was added to the table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720486/date-timestamp-to-record-when-a-record-was-added-to-the-table) - this question was asked just yesterday. Did you search first?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes use a default constraint:

```
mydatecolumn datetime 
    constraint DF_myDate DEFAULT (getdate())
```

Answer (score 15):

Yes, use a `default`:

```
create table test_table (d_col datetime default current_timestamp)
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, use a default constraint of `GetDate()`

Answer (score 2):

Very simple. When designing the table in SSMS, set the field's default value to `getdate()`

Answer (score 1):

Just simply write  **reg_date timestamp default current_timestamp on update current_timestamp**

Answer (score 0):

create table FACT_LO ([LOAD_DATE] [datetime] default getdate())