# How to Get Date from SQL server and store it in SQL Database in single query

Tags: c#, winforms, t-sql, date

I am working in c# WinForms on a project that adds members to a team. What I want to do is when members are added to a team the day on which the are added should also store in their rows in the Member table.
I know to get the current date in SQL server is

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE());
```

and to store date in the server is

```
INSERT INTO Date_Table VALUES('2020-04-11');
```

but I am looking for a single query or way to store data in my table with other data from different text boxes in the forms.

The other idea to do so is to store date by getting the current date from C#

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
```

The second thing is I want to store my date in `dd-MM-yyyy` formate.

Comment: Dates are not stored as text in a database, so the format they appear in is irrelevant. Date formatting should only take place in the UI layer of your application.

Answer (score 2):

Either of these queries will insert a record with a date provided by the server:

```
INSERT INTO Members(Name, CreatedDate)
VALUES( 'John Smith', GetUtcDate() )


INSERT INTO Members(Name, CreatedDate)
SELECT 'John Smith', GetUtcDate()
```

The latter doesn't need a from clause. I'd recommend you use UTC for all your date storage, particularly if any aspect of your application has international reach. Converting from UTC to a local time is trivial, and working in UTC means you're not subject to variations such as daylight savings causing time repeats in logs etc

If you're using it from c# and want to parameterize (you should always want to parameterize your queries):

```
INSERT INTO Members(Name, Birthdate, CreatedDate)
VALUES(@name, @bday, GetUtcDate())

INSERT INTO Members(Name, Birthdate, CreatedDate)
SELECT @name, @bday, GetUtcDate()


cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = "John Smith";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@bday", SqlDbType.Date).Value = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1); //dates are stored as dates, not formatted strings 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Store your date as a date. If you want it in a particular format, ToString it on the way out

Comment: In the SQL example, using `GetUtcDate` won't return the SQL Server's date unless the server's timezone happens to be UTC. I think you'd want to use `GETDATE`. I think could also simplify the insert by using `VALUES('John Smith', GETDATE())`.

Comment: I am going to insert it in the table as `Default`   as in (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10740293/insert-an-insertion-date-value-into-a-sql-table-automatically). So don't need to provide it in the query.