# Mysql Triggers for timestamps

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a mysql table with several columns :
id, starttime (timestamp), endtime (timestamp), status.

I would like to add triggers to :

- automatically set the timestamp to the 'starttime' field when a new entry is created
- automatically set the timestamp to the 'endtime' field when the corresponding line 'status' is set to "CLOSED"

Newbie in mysql, I have difficulties declaring these triggers...

Thank you for your help,

Comment: For 1. you can use a default value. For 2 you need a trigger

Comment: What kind of difficulties? If you don't share your code and explain your exact problems this is not a question but a free code request ;-)

Comment: regarding your first question, please check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720486/date-timestamp-to-record-when-a-record-was-added-to-the-table

Comment: regarding your second question, you can use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296313/mysql-trigger-after-update-only-if-row-has-changed (because your _new_ status (**closed**) is different then your _old_ one).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete solution :
(for drupal use)

Trigger 1 :

```
   $slqquery = 'CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_name` ';
   $slqquery .= 'BEFORE INSERT ON `table_name` ';
   $slqquery .= 'FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SET NEW.starttime=NOW(); END;';
   $query = db_query($slqquery);
```

Trigger 2 :

```
   $slqquery = 'CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_name` ';
   $slqquery .= 'BEFORE UPDATE ON `table_name` ';
   $slqquery .= 'FOR EACH ROW BEGIN ';
   $slqquery .= "IF (!(OLD.column_name <=> NEW.column_name) AND (NEW.column_name <=> 'WHATEVER')) THEN ";
   $slqquery .= 'SET NEW.endtime=NOW(); ';
   $slqquery .= 'END IF; END;';
   $query = db_query($slqquery);
```

if it can help.