# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'EntryDate', table 'eApps.Logs.dbo.Logs'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm getting this error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'EntryDate', table 'eApps.Logs.dbo.Logs'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

I have a standard add function to EF 6

```
    public Logs AddLog(Logs p)
    {
        Logs.Add(p);
        SaveChanges();
        return p;
    }
```

I've defined the field in my class as:

```
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }
```

Should I be populating this field in my controller at all?

Comment: Specify it as nullable `public DateTime? EntryDate { get; set; }`

Comment: business rules on the table require the field to be not null

Comment: You won't be able to write the field because is marked as computed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a constraint on the EntryDate field in SQL Server to default this field to GETDATE()

Answer (score 1):

Please note that column `EntryDate` in table does not allow NULL. Hence, you must ensure that object `p` got valid date. Other option could be to change table schema and modify `EntryDate` column to accept NULL.

Comment: The field is intended as a database generated timestamp for each log

Comment: You can create a constraint to auto populate datetime field whenever record is added. You can get help from [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720486/date-timestamp-to-record-when-a-record-was-added-to-the-table)

Comment: If you are using CodeFirst to generate your schema, then add this attribute to your property: [SqlDefaultValue(DefaultValue = "getdate()")]  If you are using database first and have a schema pre-defined, then as Manoj points out, add the default constraint to your table. The DatabaseGenerated attribute just tells EF that the DB will handle generation, but you need to set up the DB to generate that value.